# Matlab Simulink enumeration mapping

Tags: matlab, enums, simulink

I want to map 2 enumeration lists in simulink in a way that it is easy to see the connection between the 2 maps using their names instead of their values. How can this be done?

Thank you!

**Example:**

Actions:

```
classdef(Enumeration) Actions < Simulink.IntEnumType
    enumeration
        Off(1)
        PowerOn(2)
        PowerOff(3)
    end
end
```

States:

```
classdef(Enumeration) States < Simulink.IntEnumType
    enumeration
        START(1000)
        RUNNING(1002)
        STOPPED(1003)
        OFF(1004)
    end
end
```

The connections would be like this:

```
States.START -> Actions.PowerOn
States.RUNNING -> Actions.PowerOn
States.STOPPED -> Actions.PowerOff
States.OFF -> Actions.Off
```

Comment: Are you looking for a simulink block for this mapping?

Comment: It should be used in simulink model but if the solution exist of a block with some extra code\components it is fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this the common practice is to use a [Multiport Switch](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/multiportswitch.html). Use the values for `States` as data port indices and the `Actions` as [Enumerated Constants](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/enumeratedconstant.html) like this:

[image]

The settings for the Multiport Switch should look like this:

[image]

I have made the data types of signals visible to see that we map a signal of data type `States` to a signal of data type `Actions`.